# How can I query multiple columns from a drop down menu and a count of a certain column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to generate a report for a user to select from a drop-down menu. I'd like to be able to pull multiple columns from a selected drop down. And, if possible, get a certain count for a certain column.

So far I've only been able to select one column and get a count from it.

```
=QUERY(A2:O20,"SELECT M, count(M) Where E ='" &B23 & "' group by M",0)
```

I'd like to somehow to continue selecting certain columns and have them display when a user selects from the drop-down menu, as well as keeping my current work (The count from M)

Comment: Here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QBClQxvHnusATr7dpkVEcDNDgZI6xbtkIy9iU8So0w4/edit?usp=sharing

Also thanks for editing my horrible grammar..

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Here I created a new sheet that should be public. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15saKcqyRxlHRm1Pb7Dk27TSn8oQnSuWznCD0tBla-ho/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### compact mode:

```
={"select Interface", L1;
 QUERY(A2:H, "select A,count(A) where D='"&L1&"' group by A label count(A)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select B,count(B) where D='"&L1&"' group by B label count(B)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select C,count(C) where D='"&L1&"' group by C label count(C)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select E,count(E) where D='"&L1&"' group by E label count(E)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select F,count(F) where D='"&L1&"' group by F label count(F)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select G,count(G) where D='"&L1&"' group by G label count(G)''");
 QUERY(A2:H, "select H,count(H) where D='"&L1&"' group by H label count(H)''")}
```

[image: 0]

---

### labeled mode:

```
=IF(K1<>"", {
 QUERY(A1:H, "select A,count(A) where D='"&K1&"' group by A label count(A)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select B,count(B) where D='"&K1&"' group by B label count(B)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select C,count(C) where D='"&K1&"' group by C label count(C)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select E,count(E) where D='"&K1&"' group by E label count(E)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select F,count(F) where D='"&K1&"' group by F label count(F)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select G,count(G) where D='"&K1&"' group by G label count(G)''", 1);
 QUERY(A1:H, "select H,count(H) where D='"&K1&"' group by H label count(H)''", 1)}, )
```

[image: 0]

**note:** green background and bold labels can be auto-set via conditional formatting

---

### expanded mode:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(A1:H, 
 "select A,count(A),B,count(B),C,count(C),D,count(D),
         E,count(E),F,count(F),G,count(G),H,count(H) 
  where D='"&K1&"' 
  group by A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H", 1)), "^count.*", ""))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Beautiful! expanded mode is what I was trying to accomplish! Thank you for spending the time to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I set up a copy of your sheet that stacks the count of each column as a report based on which value is selected from the drop down.  The formula is in cell K1 and I've moved the drop down to cell J1:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccFgll7mW2rNs6m9gHUAx7ObsZ8n4GFjMc2cZS0nX68/edit?usp=sharing

The syntax of the formula uses ; to place each QUERY output on top of the next:

`={QUERY(ColA);QUERY(ColB);QUERY(ColC);QUERY(ColE) etc...}`